# How to Compare values in 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with values like these :

```
A : 
Product   |   Number (int)  |
Paper          10
Pen            25
Pencil         5
Eraser         6

--------------------------------------------------
B : 
Product   |   Number (int)  |
Paper          8
Pen            30
Pencil         12
Eraser         0
```

Now, I want to compare Table "B" with "A" and find Products in "B" that Number is bigger than "A"

(In this case will find "Pen" and "Pencil" from "B" )

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Just use join as shown below:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM A JOIN B
ON A.Product=B.Product AND A.`Number`<B.`Number`;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM B 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.Product=B.Product AND A.`Number`<B.`Number`);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does anyway without Join ?

Comment: @SeyedRezaRobatjazi there you go. I just added another query.